# Place images outside content containers

Tags: image, css

I'm a little new to all this so my terminology may be a bit dodgy.

On this page - [halfbakedharvest.com](http://www.halfbakedharvest.com/sage-lemon-roasted-chicken-goat-milk-brussels-sprout-pasta/) - there are images that appear at the edge of the screen - outside of the main content areas/ containers. These occur on every blog post and, no matter the length of the post, these images appear in the same relative position.

How do I replicate this?

I've tried Google for answers but I must not be using the right terminology because I have found nothing. Could it be as simple as a plugin I could use?

If it helps my site uses the genesis framework and I'm a confident novice when it comes to editing php and css.

Comment: Right click, Inspect element. What you are looking for is just inside the <body> tag, copy html and css.

Answer (score 0):

As Nath said, inspecting the elements will reveal they are using absolute positioning. [MDN absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow of the page and positions the element relative to it's nearest positioned ancestor. keywords left, right, top, and bottom used to position the element.

```
body {
/* what you want to position relative to */
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Note the relative positioning on the body.
 [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p38mwxnh/23/)